# Call method with recursion in Python

Tags: python

I am learning Python's recursion. I define a linked list where each node has `item`, `next` and `level`. I want to write a recursion to set the level from head to the tail with 0, 1, 2...

```
class LinkNode(object):
    """A node in a linked list."""

    def __init__(self, item, next=None):
        """(LinkNode, object, LinkNode) -> NoneType
        Initialize this node to store item and have next and level 0.
        """
        self.item = item
        self.left = next
        self.level = 0  # the level of the link

    def set_level(self, level):
        """(LinkNode, int) -> NoneType
        Set the level attribute of every node in the list
        for example: first node is 0, second is 1, third is 3...
        """
        if self is None:
            pass
        else:
            self.level = level
            levle = level + 1
            self.set_level(self.next, level)
```

but when I run it, i got the following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101
4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 29, in <module>   File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py",
line 21, in set_level builtins.TypeError: set_level() takes exactly 2
positional arguments (3 given)
```

Is there any problem with the recursive call?

Comment: You need `self.next.set_level(level)`. When you have `an_object.method(arg1, ...)`, this is implicitly translated to `AClass.method(an_object, arg1, ...)` which explains your error.

Comment: Which also means that `self is not None`

Comment: Yeah, the check should be `if self.next is not None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

```
levle = level + 1
```

Have a typo here. Also when calling something through class context, `self` in a method will be the caller, so when you say `self.set_level` you're actually calling:

```
set_level(self, self.next, level)
```

which is not what you want. What you do want would be something like:

```
self.next.set_level(level)
```

However given that this is a linked list, I don't actually see you setting the `level` of self.next (which looking at your `__init__` you don't seem to be setting a `self.next`, but a `self.left` instead). I would take a look over your code again and verify that the variable you're trying to access is named properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_level(self, level):
    """(LinkNode, int) -> NoneType
    Set the level attribute of every node in the list
    for example: first node is 0, second is 1, third is 3...
    """
    self.level = level
    if self.next is not None:
        self.next.set_level(level+1)
```

---

When you call `self.set_level(...)` the method `self_level` is called with the instance `self` (the object to the left of the dot) as the first argument.

So `self.set_level(self.next, level)` calls `self`'s set_level method with `self` as the first argument, `self.next` as the second argument, and `level` as the third argument.

Since `LinkNode.set_level` only takes two arguments, Python raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use `self.next.set_level(level)` instead of `self.set_level(self.next, level)`.

The problem (in execution) is in the statement:

```
self.set_level(self.next, level)
```

This means that `set_level` function requires 2 arguments, but you pass 3: `(self, self.next, level)`

When defining a class member function in Python, you add the "self" parameter (whose name is just a convention), which will identify the object on which the function applies.

So, some statement `def function(self)` get called `object.function()`, where object will be passed as self.argument.